# Prove that one can choose evenly many objects from a collection of objects in $2^{n-1}$ ways.

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the solution -
Let us prove that the number of subsets of the given set of objects with evenly many elements is the same as the number of subsets with oddly many objects. We begin by choosing one of the objects-say, $A$, which will play a special part further in the solution. Now, we will split all the subsets in pairs in such a way that each pair consists of two subsets, one of which always has evenly many elements and another which contains oddly many elements. To do this, we consider one arbitrary subset of the given set of objects and, if it contains $A$ as its element, we remove $A$ from it; if it does not, we add $A$ to it. The resulting subset will be in the same pair with the original one, and the number of elements in these two subsets have different parity. It is easy to see that if the subset $S$ generates the subset $S'$ ,then this construction applied to $S'$ gives us $S$. Therefore, we have the required splitting, and the proof is complete.

Can you re-engineer the same proof so that it's more understandable? Or can you explain the same proof in a simpler way?

Comment: One way to rephrase what you wrote is: $S\mapsto S\Delta\{A\}$ (where $\Delta$ denotes [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)) is a bijection exchaning odd subsets with even subsets.

Comment: Or another way I've heard: toggling whether $A$ is in the set gives a bijection between even and odd subsets.

Comment: And one “algebraic” proof consists in expanding $(1-1)^n=0$ with the Binomial theorem and moving every second term to the other side of the equality.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S = {1,2,3}$

All subsets $= \{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,1\}, \{1,2,3\}$

Let $3$ be the special number.

Take the first subset. And we by adding $3$, we get {} and {3}

And for second subset, we get $\{1,3\}$ and $\{1\}$

This construction shows that we have now pairs of subsets, where the pairs are of opposite parity.

Therefore we are done.

Comment: OP asked for explain proof in a simpler way. What better way than to show an example of the logic?

Comment: Ok, will delete comment.

Comment: The downvotes in MSE is mind boggling. No explanation. whatsoever. Poor etiquette!

Comment: That was my downvote. I tried to upvote to counter it, but got the message from stock exchange that I could not do so until the post itself was edited. I don't really understand why they did not permit me to change my downvote. Maybe you could try just adding a general explanation of OP's situation as an edit to your answer [which was after all only an example, not what OP requested]. If so I can try again to counter my downvote.

Comment: I appreciate your candor @coffeemath. Thank you!!